# Handling large dense matrices by mutiple GPUs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, parallel-processing, gpu, distributed-computing

Just matrix A times matrix B(and other simple operations), but each matrix (A or B) is so large for a single GPU to store.

```matlab
A = rand(10000,10000)
A = distributed(A)
spmd
%     gpuDevice
    A = gpuArray(A)
    
end
```

My solution is failed, due to "GPU arrays support only fundamental numeric or logical data types."

If I manually distribute parts of the matrix to the each GPU，I have to deal with communication time between GPUs (each parts of my matrix) by myself, furthermore, I can't use lots of funtions such as eig or max directly.

I have no idea whether matlab already have some solution (just like using distributed array to deal with communication time between each works) to handle this problem.

Comment: I think (not 100% sure) that MATLAB does not have support for "single operation, multiple GPU" kind of thing. You can use `parfor` or `spdm` to call pieces of your problem in different GPUs simultaneously, but I don't think you can make a big matrix multiplication that gets distributed along GPUs. You are going to need to write it yourself. I think... https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/run-matlab-functions-on-multiple-gpus.html

Comment: Thank you so much!
Actually I have done something like that in Matlab before, and 90% of time is used for move data to GPU. Because python have some tensor-based frameworks for large-scale data computation within some special design to deal with communication time cost, I thought Matlab have something too.

Now, it seems I have no choose but to move my codes on python.

Comment: well, if you code it yourself, there is no need to get the results back to CPU, therefore the time should be the same. If its because of convenience, yeah, makes sense to change to python, but its not because MATLAB cant do it. The CPU-GPU transfers are language agnostic

Comment: If I put matrix A on GPU one, matrix B on GPU two, all GPUs belong to same cluster. And I have to choose to save C ( = A*B) on GPU three. So this process have to use datas on different GPUs to do this calculation. is this process, that datas move between GPUs, faster than move data between RAM and GPUs?

Comment: First of all, results of acomputation must be stored in the same hardware that computed them. You seem to be describing GPUs as storage devices, that is not how it works. You need to split the mathematical problem e.g. have some rows and some columns of A and B on GPU 1 and compute partial C. Same on GPU 2 etc. Then, GPU-GPU transfers are fast, and depedns on your computer hardware setup, extremely fast. But we are getting into details here.